# PHP вывести из базы данные с разными значениями типа колонки

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте, у меня вопрос. Допустим есть база со столбцами

*Пример блоков (в них содержится код запроса) и все блоки отдельны друг от друга.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**id -- name -- type -- text**

и несколько запросов к бд:

```
<?php
require "подключение";
$sql = "SELECT name, id FROM таблица WHERE type='такой-то'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "".$row['id']."";}} 
else {
echo "пусто";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

и таких запров на странице порядком десяти штук...

Как эти запросы можно **объединить в один запрос**?

вот пример как выглядет код на странице сейчас (три блока):

```
блок1

<?php
require "подключение";
$sql = "SELECT name, id FROM таблица WHERE type='1'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "".$row['id']."";}} 
else {
echo "пусто";
}
$conn->close();
?>

блок2

<?php
require "подключение";
$sql = "SELECT name, id FROM таблица WHERE type='2'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "".$row['id']."";}} 
else {
echo "пусто";
}
$conn->close();
?>

блок3

<?php
require "подключение";
$sql = "SELECT name, id FROM таблица WHERE type='3'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "".$row['id']."";}} 
else {
echo "пусто";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `WHERE type in ('1','2','3')`

Comment: ну, запустите цикл, в котором `type` как `i++` и подставляйте в запрос.

Comment: @Даниил вариант от участника splash58 разве не подходит? Просто перечислите нужные вам поля

Comment: Каждый блок отделен (добавил картинку) и в каждом блоке выводится информация SELECT name, id FROM таблица WHERE type='тип' (имя и ай-ди) именно для конкретного блока т.е. другими словами "тип"- это и есть название одного блока, а вариант WHERE type in ('1','2','3') выводит данные только один раз

Comment: `SELECT name, id, type FROM таблица WHERE type in ('1','2','3')`. Далее средствами php формируете три массива (по колонке `type`) и забиваете данные в свои блоки

Comment: добавляете `order by type` и в цикле чтения смотрите, если тип записи отличается от того типа который был у предыдущей (запоминаете его в какой нибудь переменной), то выводите закрытие предыдущего блока и открытие нового